# Replace multiple Strings in a file using fileinput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace multiple strings in a file.

My file may have some contents like this:

## file1:

```
#groovy
some test
some more test
REPLACE_1
REPLACE_OPTIONAL_1
REPLACE_2
end test
```

I am trying to use fileinput module to replace above text but its not working as expected. My method is something like this:

```
    import fileinput
    def replace_method():
        file_path = './file1.txt'
        try:
            with fileinput.FileInput(file_path, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
                for line in file:
                    print (line.replace('REPLACE_1', 'replaced_value1'), end='')
                    print (line.replace('REPLACE_OPTIONAL_1', 'replaced_value2'), end='')
                    print (line.replace('REPLACE_OPTIONAL_2', 'replaced_value3'), end='')
                   print (line.replace('REPLACE_2', 'replaced_value4'), end='')

        except Exception as e:
            print (str(e))
```

Above code works but it prints everyline 4 times in the new modified file. I believe this is something to do with line.replace which Imight be using wrongly.

Can you please help me fixing this.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't print 4 times

```
import fileinput
def replace_method():
    file_path = './file1.txt'
    try:
        with fileinput.FileInput(file_path, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.replace('REPLACE_1', 'replaced_value1')
                line = line.replace('REPLACE_OPTIONAL_1', 'replaced_value2')
                line = line.replace('REPLACE_OPTIONAL_2', 'replaced_value3')
                line = line.replace('REPLACE_2', 'replaced_value4')
                print (line, end='')
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are printing the line four times instead of one. The fix could look like:

```
import fileinput

def replace_method():
    file_path = './file1.txt'
    try:
        with fileinput.FileInput(file_path, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
            for line in file:
                line.replace('REPLACE_1', 'replaced_value1')
                line.replace('REPLACE_OPTIONAL_1', 'replaced_value2')
                line.replace('REPLACE_OPTIONAL_2', 'replaced_value3')
                line.replace('REPLACE_2', 'replaced_value4')
                print(line, end='')
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
```